# dynamic array elements through loop

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an array of images in javascript for my website when I declare array size it is working but when I am trying to take it as a dynamic array it is not showing images. can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
var theImages = new Array()
for (i = 0; i < theImages.length; i++) 
{  
  theImages[i] = i+".jpg"
}
```

Comment: You don't declare a length for the Array, so the length would seem to be `0` and the `for` loop probably won't run.

Comment: please add code of your html and edit you js code

Comment: 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg..... Is that what you really want?

Comment: What do you think the value of `theImages.length` is when you do that? Try adding `console.log(theImages.length)`

Comment: @epascarello yes !! As there are so many images I want to assign through for loop

Comment: @Herohtar tried console.log(theImages.length), didnt work

Comment: That wasn't supposed to solve the problem, but output the value of the length to the browsers console, which if you looked at it would show `0`. In other words, your loop never executes because the array has nothing in it.

Comment: @DavidThomas is there any way that I can assign images into the array without explicitly assigning each of them

Comment: oh yeah .. understood .can you suggest a solution ?@Herohtar

Comment: Are you sure you need an array if you don't know how many there are going to be? Why not just create the image name dynamically when you need it?

Answer (score 0):

The initial size of theImages is 0.

You need to use

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{  
  theImages[i] = i+".jpg";
}
```

replace 5 by the number of images you have.

Comment: As the number of images is not fixed and keeps changing, I tried images.length. can you suggest any other solution

Comment: @sarvaniviswanadha To use `images.length` you have to make the size of the `images` array the number of images you want. But if you don't know that, how do you do that?

Comment: create a function that get the number of images and replace 5 by that function.

Comment: javascript is flexible about the size of an array.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are looping an empty array, the length/size of the array is 0 because you have just created a new array and are looping it without any elements in it yet.

If you wish to add all images to an array, you will have to know the total number of images you have/ count of images, and then run the loop to add the images in the array, which you were able to do successfully you said.

```
var theImages = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
{  
theImages[i] = i+".jpg";
}
```

If you are getting the image names for SQL, it is a different query you want to use, let me know if that is what you are looking for.